# How can I send fetching data from database via mail

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

```
<?php       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<br>  ". $row["description"]. " <br>";
    } 
?>
```

When user enter their name and submit based on that name result will be displayed from database in a separate page. I added mail function. Mail function is working. But How to send mail with displaying that result(fetching data from database)  in PHP

```
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message = $row["description"];

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

- Mail is sending Empty. Its not displaying that fetching data from database.

Comment: `$subject2 =/= $subject` Is it this simple

Comment: And do you have a variable called `$headers` and if so what does it contain

Comment: @RiggsFolly  $headers = "From:" . $from;    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission"; $to      = 'mymailid';  $message = $row["description"]; mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);  Here mail function is working. How fetching data is not added in mail. Its going as empty mail

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First:

```
var_dump($result->fetch_assoc());exit;
```

If the array contains a value, then go with this:

```
<?php       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<br>  ". $row["description"]. " <br>";
    } 
?
```

Here you get the result from an associative array. Store it in a variable like this:

```
//store data in Description variable
$description='';
<?php       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $description=$description."<br>".$row["description"]."<br>";
    } 
?>

//send mail
mail($to,$subject,$description,$headers);
```

Comment: whats in `$message`;

Comment: Thank You. I added above two code means result is displaying. but not sending to mail. if i add  $description='';
<?php       
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $description=$description."<br>".$row["description"]."<br>";
    } 
?>   - MAil is sending but result is not displaying. But i need result should be displayed as well as needs to send mail also.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
$to = 'You@example.com';
$subject = "Copy of your form submission";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$headers .= "From: you@example.com\n";
$message = $row["description"];

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: I tried this code already. But mail is sending as empty. Its not taking mysql fetch data.data is displaying. $message = $row["description"];But not sending to mail id. $message is not sending to mail.

Answer (score 0):

you can use another and best method for send email , [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) can work in composer and include class for send email.
you can send with smtp and in all services google , yahoo , ... dot get spam folder , **just in inbox**

```
   //Create the Transport.
    $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.ddd.com', 587, 'tls')
        ->setUsername('noreply@ddd.com')
        ->setPassword('iFv0(W6Ltl=r')
        ->setStreamOptions(array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        )
        );

    //Create the message
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

    //Give the message a subject
    $message->setSubject($title)
      ->setFrom('noreply@ddd.com')
      ->setTo($email) 
      ->setBody($title, 'text/html')
      ->addPart($body, 'text/html');

    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    //Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    if ($result) {
      echo "Email sent successfully";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Email failed to send";
    }
```